# Model-View... for Blazor

Tags: model-view-controller, mvvm, mvp, blazor

Despite I google-d for some time I couldn't find any of the **Model-View-XYZ** framework implementations for server-side Blazor, that is **Razor Components** (**XYZ** stand for any of the following: **Controller**, **Presenter**, **ViewModel**).

If anyone knows of such an implementation, no matter in what stage of development it is, please let me know. Thanks a lot in advance.

**EDIT**: The question is if *someone has encountered*, or *takes part in development of such a framework*.

The question is **absolutely simple** - has someone encountered some info on the Internet about such a framework targeting Razor Components (aka server-side Blazor), since I  haven't so far.

Comment: You should have googled Asp.Net Core MVC. It's all there...

Comment: @Isaac. ...and some outside of it.

Comment: What is your expectation of such framework?

Answer (score 10):

I'm not 100% sure what your question is so I'm taking a stab at what I think you're asking.

It's important to understand that Blazor is not opinionated about how you choose to structure your code. The team have been very clear that they will not force any patterns on developers. This means that you are free to structure your code how you feel is best.

If you're interested in MVVM for example, Jeremy Likness has a [great blog post](https://blog.jeremylikness.com/mvvm-support-in-blazor-dbc38060a4a0) covering using this pattern in Blazor apps. But if you are looking for official docs covering this then you're out of luck.

Hope this helps, if not please clarify what it is you're looking for.

Comment: This is exactly what I say, only said another way. And, IMHO, MVVM is the worst of the three frameworks I mentioned. So, again, please read my question and if you know something about such a framework I'd be grateful to know about it.

Comment: Would you like to clarify what your actual question is then? 

I don't think I've said what you said in a different way at all. Also, I said if you're interested in MVVM then there was a good article. As, once again, you've not actually asked a question there is not much to aim at here.

Comment: @ChrisSainty The referenced article is horrible. This will result in extremely unnecessary calls of `StateHasChanged()`. You might wanna read the official MSDN documentation about [Blazor performance considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/performance).

Comment: @ˈvɔlə I didn’t write it, I merely said it was an article (from a well known name at Microsoft. Jeremy was a senior cloud advocate and is now PM for the EF Core product) that talked about implementing MVVM with Blazor. It was also 3 years ago and things have changed a lot! Personally, I’m not a fan of MVVM and I’d never choose to use it with Blazor.

Answer (score 2):

Blazor itself is an MVVM framework. The HTML in your Razor Component is your View. The `@functions` section is your ViewModel and you can use POCO classes for your Models.

Comment: Really? In @Chris Sainty answer there's a link, so you might consider reading it.

Comment: The link is about providing a _better_ MVVM, the bare Blazor approach is an (incomplete) MVVM pattern. Iirc the separation of @functions into another file/class is under discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I released [HanumanInstitute.MvvmDialogs](https://github.com/mysteryx93/HanumanInstitute.MvvmDialogs) as a platform-agnostic solution to display dialogs. It's currently implemented for WPF and Avalonia.

Blazor support could easily be added by copying from the Avalonia branch. If someone wants to take on that task.

Answer (score 0):

After reading about it I implemented this MVVM design for Blazor Webassembly + WebApi app. A ViewModel is injected as transient into the View and the View calls the ViewModel's Initialize() which causes updates to ViewModel's properties which fires property-update events which are handled by the View to update the presentation state. The ViewModel also handles user actions that come from the View. ResourceApi is injected as singleton into the ViewModel which subscribes to resource-updated events. Model caching can be implemented at the ResourceApi layer. An action that updates a resource raises a resource-updated event which causes the ViewModel to reload the data and in turn raise its own property-changed event which is picked up by the View to update the presentation using binding.

[image]